# SELECT query Prepared Statement output

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm still new to the prepared statement, so forgive me for my stupid mistakes.

At the moment I try to select something from outside the database. Either though there is no output.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT title FROM media");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $title);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($a);
$stmt->fetch();
printf("Title: ", $title, $a);
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: you are binding to a placeholder that's not in you query? [see the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: um... bind what? as in `WHERE which_column = ???` could be anything really.

Comment: `SELECT title ...` + `$stmt->bind_param("s", $title);` - that doesn't sound right. Do you want to select the title or discriminate by the title?

Comment: undefined `$title` notice, as your query totally depends on it for success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to output something from a prepared statement, you have to select something from a database first.

if you want to select only one title, then you have to add a WHERE condition

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT title FROM media WHERE title=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $title);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($a);
$stmt->fetch();
echo "Title: $title : $a");
$stmt->close();
```

but you have to realize that **a condition should match the actual title that exists in database**. Otherwise nothing will be printed.

if you want to select all titles, then remove binding and add a loop

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT title FROM media");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($a);
while ($stmt->fetch())
{
    echo "Title: $a";
}
$stmt->close();
```

by the popular demand added minimal error handling

Comment: At the first code: after this I still got no output (besides "Title:").
At the second code: same result as first code only it displays 3 times "Title:", which is a good thing since there are 3 records in the database. Also changed $title to $a, since there is no $title variable.
Both give no error output.

Comment: Ok, it did the trick second code I forgot to change printf to echo (my bad).
First code I changed "title=?" to "id=3" and removed "$stmt->bind_param("s", $title);", which made it work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Add the bind param to your query like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT title FROM media WHERE title = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $title);
```

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for more information.

Comment: After this I still got no output (besides "Title:").